# Can I make Selenium WebDriver wait before every action? (For Debugging Purposes)

Tags: java, selenium, wait, bdd, webdriverwait

I'm working on a BDD project.
Sometimes the tests go too fast for the developers to see what is happening when they run them.

At the moment I'm solving it placing something like

```
Thread.sleep(humanWaitTime)
```

before each method but it defeats the purpose of writing efficient code.

Is there any way to set this globally so that it can easily be taken out when doing a regression test and not clutter my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebDriverEventListener and fake wait for not existing element,
you should:

1. create class: `public class CustomDriverListener implements
   WebDriverEventListener` and implement all methods
2. in this class add next method:

   `private void fakeWaiter(WebDriver driver) {
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
   try {
   wait.until(listenerDriver -> listenerDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//[.='it'sFakeElement']")));
   } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e) {
   //ignore it
   }
   }`
3. add invocation of this method to methods that you need, like:

   `@Override
   public void afterFindBy(By by, WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
       fakeWaiter(driver);
   }
   @Override
   public void afterClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
       fakeWaiter(driver);
   }
   @Override
   public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement element, WebDriver driver, CharSequence[] keysToSend) {
       fakeWaiter(driver);
   }
   @Override
   public void afterScript(String script, WebDriver driver) {
       fakeWaiter(driver);
   }`
4. Create EventFiringWebDriver object and register your
   **CustomDriverListener**:

   `WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();

   EventFiringWebDriver driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(webDriver);
   driver.register(new CustomDriverListener());`

Now if you use "**driver**" in your tests all operations will be slower(depend on timer in **fakeWaiter** method)

P.S. sorry for bad formatting =(

Answer (score -1):

You can probably use Implicit wait,

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Lets say on top of your code block, you write:-

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Then, before each line of your code, the webdriver instance will wait for 15 seconds, you don't have to give wait times after each statement.

The implicit wait will tell to the web driver to wait for certain amount of time before it throws a "No Such Element Exception". The default setting is 0. Once we set the time, web driver will wait for that time before throwing an exception.